# How to get fiddler to trace web traffic when running under a another user

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, fiddler

I have added following into application.config (of console application) and still doesn't collect traffic when its run under a different user account on same machine.

```
<system.net>
 <defaultProxy>
  <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
 </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```